# How to implement tensorflow cosine_decay

Tags: tensorflow

When I call the cosine_decay function in tensorflow, it shows this error:

`'<' not supported between instances of 'CosineDecay' and 'int'`

Here is my code:

```
  decay_steps = 1000
  lr_decayed_fn = tf.keras.experimental.CosineDecay(initial_learning_rate=0.01, decay_steps=1000)

  model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=lr_decayed_fn), loss=dice_coef_loss, metrics=[dice_coef])
```

I just followed the tutorial on tensorflow and I don't know why there is this error

Answer (score 0):

Change `Adam(lr=lr_decayed_fn)` to `Adam(learning_rate=lr_decayed_fn)`

The Adam optimizer call in tensorflow v2 needs learning_rate to be spelled out, it does not take the argument as "lr." See this issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44172